# Черный экран после apt upgrade на kali linux на виртуалке VMware

Tags: linux, kali-linux, виртуальная-машина

При первом запуске kali linux на  VMware все работало, но после apt upgrade и перезапуске виртуальной машины kali linux зависает и просто черный экран.

Comment: попробуйте предоставить чуточку больше информации. Я понимаю, что это кали линукс и все такое, но все же. Когда именно появляется черный экран? сразу или "какие то буковки успевают пробежать"? а может в грубе попробовать поискать безопасный (или как оно там называется) вид загрузки?

Comment: Когда запускаешь виртуальную машину там показывает окно ввода логина и пароля, после ввода выходит черный экран.Я где то читал что это какой-то файл и его нужно удалить на там ничего про то что это за файл не говорилось. Все нормально работает если не обновлять, но мне хочется узнать как это решить.

Comment: такая проблема скорее всего связана с видеодрайвером. Так как у Вас оно в виртуалбоксе, то нужно обновить и гостевые драйвера от него. Но некоторые поставщики это забывают сделать. И тогда нужно ручками пересобрать, что не всегда бывает возможно

Comment: Значит эту проблему никак не решить?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/LinuxAdditionsDebug  - проблему решить можно, но думаю, лучше воспользоваться дистрибутивами, которые более дружелюбны к пользователю - Gentoo или Arch.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, теперь я понял почему выскакивает черный экран.

Comment: разберетесь - пишите ответ с фиксом

Comment: Значит мне надо драйвера переустановить?

Comment: скорее всего. Все зависит от того, сколько именно у Вас обновилось. А возможно, нужно установить новую версию драйвера, совместимую с новым ядром

Comment: Хорошо, еще раз вам спасибо